# iOS Swift Why can't height of UILabel text be made bigger?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want the UILabel text to be larger, but when I change value_row_height, there is no change in size.

```
var value_row_x = 30
var value_row_y = 100
var value_row_height = 320    
var value_row_width = 30


let heart_rate_title_UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: value_row_x, y: value_row_y, width: value_row_width, height: value_row_height ))
heart_rate_title_UILabel.center = CGPoint( x: value_row_x + value_row_width / 2, y: value_row_y + value_row_height/2 )
heart_rate_title_UILabel.textAlignment = .left
heart_rate_title_UILabel.text = "heart: "
heart_rate_title_UILabel.sizeToFit()
self.view.addSubview( heart_rate_title_UILabel)
```

UPDATE:
I added following code, but size failed to change...
heart_rate_title_UILabel.font = label.font.withSize(20)
heart_rate_title_UILabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1    //or whatever suits your need
heart_rate_title_UILabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
heart_rate_title_UILabel.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
heart_rate_title_UILabel.numberOfLines = 0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked jim-dandy....

```
            value_row_y -= 10          
            value_row_x += 45 + inter_value_gap_pix       // + width of heart rate value
            let title_UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: value_row_x, y: value_row_y, width: value_row_width, height: value_row_height ))
            title_UILabel.center = CGPoint( x: value_row_x + value_row_width / 2, y: value_row_y + value_row_height/2 )
            title_UILabel.textAlignment = .left
            title_UILabel.text = " RSP: "
            self.view.addSubview( title_UILabel)
            // set font height to biggest (ie. label height)...
                title_UILabel.numberOfLines = 1;
                title_UILabel.font = title_UILabel.font.withSize(30)
```

Comment: How is this different from what I said?

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the physical height of the label. You are not saying *anything* about what the *text* size should be. Text size is a matter of setting the label's *font* (which includes size).